# SQL Server DateTime Intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, average

In a table, I have data coming in from sensors. The activity value is sent by a sensor every 15 minutes. Now, I want to calculate average of these values 2 times a day. As in, the 1st average of a day will be the average of values from 00:00:00 to 12:00:00 and the 2nd average for the same day will be between the time 12:00:00 and 23:59:59.

My `TimeStampByNode` column stores datetime in the format `datetime2`, 
i.e. "2015-09-02 02:03:04"

I used this query to get the daily average, i.e. of all 24 hours;

```
SELECT 
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TimeStampByNode), MONTH(TimeStampByNode), DAY(TimeStampByNode)), 
    ROUND(AVG(Value), 2) 
FROM 
    data_record2 
WHERE 
    Node_ID = 55554321 AND Value_Type = 'Activity'
GROUP BY 
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TimeStampByNode), MONTH(TimeStampByNode), DAY(TimeStampByNode))
ORDER BY  
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TimeStampByNode), MONTH(TimeStampByNode), DAY(TimeStampByNode)) DESC
```

How do I modify this to get 2 daily averages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing two different averages per day? The NULL returned in ELSE cases makes sure those are not put into averages.

```
SELECT 
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TimeStampByNode), MONTH(TimeStampByNode), DAY(TimeStampByNode)), 
     -- Start --
    ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH, TimeStampByNode) < 12 
          THEN Value ELSE NULL END), 2) as AVG_AM,
    ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH, TimeStampByNode) >= 12 
          THEN Value ELSE NULL END), 2) as AVG_PM
    -- End --
FROM 
    data_record2 
WHERE 
    Node_ID = 55554321 AND Value_Type = 'Activity'
GROUP BY 
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TimeStampByNode), MONTH(TimeStampByNode), DAY(TimeStampByNode))
ORDER BY  
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TimeStampByNode), MONTH(TimeStampByNode), DAY(TimeStampByNode)) DESC
```

(Missing bracket edited)

Comment: I'm getting an error stating "The AVG function requires 1 argument(s)."

Comment: It's returning wrong calculations. The 1st answer is returning right values. Could it have anything to do with passing nulls in the scenario where case isn't satisfied?

Comment: Ah - second condition should be  >= 12

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following condition to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
 ...
GROUP BY (...), case when (DATEPART(hh, TimeStampByNode) < 12) then 1 else 0 end
 ...
```

So this will become:

```
SELECT 
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TimeStampByNode), MONTH(TimeStampByNode), DAY(TimeStampByNode)), 
    ROUND(AVG(Value), 2) 
FROM 
    data_record2 
WHERE 
    Node_ID = 55554321 AND Value_Type = 'Activity'
GROUP BY 
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TimeStampByNode), MONTH(TimeStampByNode), DAY(TimeStampByNode))
  , case when (DATEPART(hh, TimeStampByNode) < 12) then 1 else 0 end
ORDER BY  
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TimeStampByNode), MONTH(TimeStampByNode), DAY(TimeStampByNode)) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working fine. but, how do I differentiate which value is for which part of the day?
The first value will always be for case 1? And the second for case2?

Comment: you can do the same in the select clause, if needed: `case when (DATEPART(hh, max(TimeStampByNode)) < 12) then "Before 12" else "After" end 'Type of Interval'`

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the 'Type of Interval' part!